# How to get the selected item from angular material `mat-menu`

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using an angular material menu component

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

How do I listen for selection changes? Is there a way to check which item the user selected without listening on each button separately for the click event?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to add an event listener on every button? I don't think that there is a way to know which button was clicked without separate event listeners

Comment: Because when I have 10 options, adding a listener to each button is redundant. In JS you would listen to the parent and capture the bubbling click events.

Comment: Yeah, without Angular Material you would be able to do that, but Angular Material doesn't add the buttons to the container you put them in (`mat-menu`), but rather puts them in a separate container that you don't really have access to from within the template (cdk overlay)

Comment: Guess I'll just have to open a feature request with the team.

Comment: @Mendy Or we can do it like this `<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button (click)="onClick(option)" *ngFor="let option of options" mat-menu-item>{{option}}</button>
</mat-menu>`

Comment: Right, this should work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way would be using a loop.
Something like:

```
    const options = ['option1','option2'];

    <button mat-button color="primary" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Copy</button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
            <button (click)="onClick(option)" *ngFor="let option of options" mat-menu-item>
                {{option}}
            </button>
    </mat-menu>
```